# Parasitic worm from dog?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, diseases

Last evening I found two small white worms crawling frantically across my white comforter on my bed attempting to burrow into it.. this after my roommate’s dog slept on my bed leaving copious amounts of what I presume to be flea feces (tiny curled black bits). I gathered the comforter immediately and ran outside with it. But I’m afraid for myself and my own dog. What type of worm is so very motile and frantic to burrow?

Comment: The "worms" are probably flea larvae. They are not in themselves harmful, since they feed on detritus, but they will soon turn into adult fleas. You need to treat your house and your dogs as soon as possible.

Comment: You can add a photo to a post; this is encouraged to enhance pest identification.  If it is fleas, picking up and distributing diatomaceous earth is the least hazardous way to control them.

Comment: If it's flea, also deworm the dogs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipylidium_caninum. Also, treat all dogs + cats that are around together.